# Keyboard up and down arrows used to increase decrease value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Use the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events to increase and decrease the value in label or some p tags. no need in textbox(input)

I got lot of examples but it all work in textbox.

without using mouse i need to increase value with one(1,2,3,4...n)in (onkeyup or onkeyright)
and (n.....4,3,2,1) in (onkeydown or onkeyleft) key press events on label or p tag

```
  <input type="text" size="2" value="1" />


<script>
    var $input = $('label');
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
            $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));
        } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
            $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
        }
    });
    </script>
```

this works in textbox.. how i use this in label

Comment: Store the current value of the label, add it by 1 then assign it to that label

Comment: If you want it to change the text on the label, use `$input.html()` instead of `val()`.

Comment: @BrettEast `$label.text()` would also do the trick (ignores html tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var $input = $('p');
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
        $input.text((parseInt($input.text()) + 1));
    } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
        $input.text((parseInt($input.text()) - 1));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="inputValue">0</p>
```

You were almost there, but here's what I changed to get it to work:

- Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`
- Changed to `<p>` instead of `<input>`
- Updated `$input` to match `<p>`

---

To use a `<label>` tag, just change

- `var $input = $('p');` to `var $input = $('label');` and
- `<p id="inputValue">0</p>` to `<label id="inputValue">0</label>`

e.g.

```js
var $input = $('label');
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
        $input.text((parseInt($input.text()) + 1));
    } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
        $input.text((parseInt($input.text()) - 1));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="inputValue">0</label>
```